# Spring MVC upload file to server directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I'm developing a web which have an upload PDF files feature. But I'm having an error.

Here's what ive done so far:

Multipart resolver:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
</bean>
```

form that will upload:

```
<form:form commandName="fileUpload" action="../admin/uploadPDF.do" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <form:label path="fileData">Upload a File</form:label> <br />
     <form:input type="file"  path="fileData" />
     <input type="submit" value="upload" >
</form:form>
```

Controller that catch the request the first time the user come to upload page, `AdminController.java`

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/admin/module", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String student( @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
    String message, @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
    String messageType, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model )
    {
        model.addAttribute( "message", message );
        model.addAttribute( "messageType", messageType );
        model.addAttribute( new UploadItemBean() );
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String returnVal = Credentials.checkSession( session );

        if( returnVal != null )
        {
            return returnVal;
        }

        return "als-student/module";
    }
```

Controller that will catch the request when upload file is submitted, `UploadController.java`

```
@RequestMapping( value = "*/uploadPDF", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String getPDF( @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
String message, @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
String messageType, @RequestParam( "name" )
String name, @RequestParam( "file" )
MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model )
{
    ...
  if( !file.isEmpty() )
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            System.out.println( bytes + ", " + name );
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "als-student/module";
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'fileUpload' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:90)
...
...
```

I also want to know how can I send the bean `fileUpload` to the form, because it seems that Its the one causing the error. And I also after uploading the file, how can I handle it to save to a folder in apache server ( If this is the good practice ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet

```
<form:form commandName="fileUpload" action="../admin/uploadPDF.do" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <form:label path="fileData">Upload a File</form:label> <br />
     <form:input type="file"  path="fileData" />
     <input type="submit" value="upload" >
</form:form>
```

Because of the `commandName` is expecting a model (request) attribute with the key `fileUpload`. You don't seem to be putting such an attribute in the `Model` in your handler

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/admin/module", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String student( @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
String message, @RequestParam( defaultValue = "" )
String messageType, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model )
{
    model.addAttribute( "message", message );
    model.addAttribute( "messageType", messageType );
    model.addAttribute( new UploadItemBean() );
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    String returnVal = Credentials.checkSession( session );

    if( returnVal != null )
    {
        return returnVal;
    }

    return "als-student/module";
}
```

I'll assume you want the `UploadItemBean`. Just change your code to do this

```
model.addAttribute("fileUpload", new UploadItemBean() );
```

By default, if you don't specify a key for the attribute, Spring will generate one for you based on the class name of the object, which won't match the expected `fileUpload`.

Comment: I see, That solve my first problem. My 2nd problem is how do I save the uploaded file in a folder in the server? and is't a good practice?

Comment: @newbie How you save it is up to you. I suggest you choose a dedicated folder (create it if it doesn't exist) and write your file there directly. You can do this with the `MultipartFile#transferTo` method or read the `InputStream` or `byte[]` directly and write it to some `OutputStream`. Read up on the `MultipartFile` javadoc.